# Angular directive controller scope visibility

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Question**

Why isn't `monkey` and `selected` visible to the template?

**Plunk**

http://plnkr.co/edit/djS0KWyfJNKD0tfZ0IiV?p=preview

**Code**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular
            .module('toruSelect', [])
            .directive('toruSelect', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'AE', // Allow usage as A - attribute, E - element
                    scope: { // Isolated scope
                        selected: '=' // Bi-directional binding to selected attribute,
                    },
                    controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                        $scope.monkey = 'MONKEY';
                        console.log('toruSelect.controller.$scope', $scope);
                    }]
                }
            });


        var app = angular.module('app', ['toruSelect']);
        app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.val = 'initial';
          $scope.appData = 'App data';
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>Directives and scopes..</h1>
    <div toru-select selected="val">
        <div style="color: red">RESULT: toruSelect.controller.monkey: {{monkey}}</div>
        <div>EXPECTED: toruSelect.controller.monkey: MONKEY</div>
        <div style="color: red">RESULT: toruSelect.controller.selected: {{selected}}</div>
        <div>EXPECTED: toruSelect.controller.selected: initial</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Result**

```
 Directives and scopes..

 RESULT: toruSelect.controller.monkey:
 EXPECTED: toruSelect.controller.monkey: MONKEY
 RESULT: toruSelect.controller.selected:
 EXPECTED: toruSelect.controller.selected: initial
```

Comment: There is no template in your example.

Comment: Why do you need 2 modules here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed it out on the comment of your directive, it has an isolated scope, so that value attached with `monkey` key is available on directive scope, not on controller one.

For `selected`, you have to display `{{val}}` and not `{{selected}}` as it's the variable concerned by the bi-directional binding on the directive scope.

Comment: Being new to Angular, I was expecting that "isolated scope" means, it isolates the directive from the outside world. I assumed that as the binding is inside the directive (the defining tag), the scope is visible for the template.

Comment: @mr-blackus It used to work the way I expected but was later changed for a reason - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2728-breaking-changes-in-isolate-scope-behavior-in-angularjs-1-2.htm